# Laravel- change database used by queues

Tags: php, database, queue, laravel-4, eloquent

I have created custom environment called production that have database.php and other configuration file in it. When running under production environment, the database that is being used is the one that I specified at the database.php inside the production environment folder but the queue doesn't use the production environment database. My question is how can I make the queue use my custom environment database.

Comment: Can you please provide some more information about the queue? What kind and/or provider. Does the provider pushes it, or is a worker running?

Comment: It's an aws queue that is used to send  out email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the input you given in the comments, it seems to me that your worker is picked up in another environment.

Did you specify the hostname of the machine running the worker in `bootstrap/start.php`, or is the worker started with `--env=production` in the command?